# Python encryption function, what is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, ascii

I am trying to write an Ascii encryption function in python, where a message is input and encrypted, with only the letters (not numbers or symbols) being considered.

The following functions are working and are being used:

```
def code_char(c, key):
    return chr(ord(c)+int(key))

def isletter(c):
    if 65 <= ord(c) <= 90:
        return True
    elif 97 <= ord(c) <= 122:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def code_block(word,key):
    letters = list(word)
    keys = list(key)
    coded = []
    for letter, digit in zip(letters, keys):
        coded.append(code_char(letter, digit))
    return "".join(coded)
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
def encrypt(string, key):
    for character in string:
        if isletter(character):
            return code_block(string, key)
        else:
            print("Invalid Message or Key")
```

I'm expecting

```
Ujlw    ny  h   afeuiy  slaticji!!
```

But got an output

```
Ujlw%oz(
```

Don't know what is going on here???

Just a stupid student so don't go ham.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I suggest adding print statements or using a debugger to see what your code is doing at each step.

Comment: You are writing return "".join(encryption) while encryption has been initialised as an empty list. Therefore you are getting blank.

Comment: Edited above @Code-Apprentice

Comment: So how can I add something to the empty list? I am trying to add the encrypted message to the empty list so that is what is returned. Is this the best way to do so? @KaushalKumarSingh

Comment: do you mean for `code_block(string, key)` to be appended to `encryption`?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use `c.islpha()` to check if `c` is a letter.

Comment: Change of plan, I've removed the lists altogether, realised they were pointless. However I am still getting this weird output? Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnColeman My assignment states I am not allowed to use the in-built functions unfortunatley

Comment: But you *are* using built-in functions/methods. Can you really use the string method `join()` but not the string method `isalpha()`?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and write out your algorithm **in words**. When you do this, you will see that some of your code doesn't really make sense for solving this particular problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yup! That very function is the one mentioned that we are not allowed to use.

Comment: Well I guess "because my instructor insists" is a perfectly good answer to my question "why reinvent the wheel?' That isn't a criticism of your instructor -- reinventing a great many wheels is part of learning to program.

Answer (score 0):

encryption has been initialised as an empty list and its value has never been updated.

Plus the above encryption supports encryption of characters other than letters, so you don't need to check if they are letter or not.

Try the following

```
def code_char(c, key):
    return chr(ord(c)+int(key))

def isletter(c):
    if 65 <= ord(c) <= 90:
        return True
    elif 97 <= ord(c) <= 122:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def code_block(word,key):
    letters = list(word)
    keys = list(key)
    coded = []
    len_key = len(key)
    counter = 0
    for letter in word:
        if isletter(letter):
            coded.append(code_char(letter, key[counter]))
            counter = (counter + 1)%len_key
        else:
            coded.append(letter)

    return "".join(coded)

def encrypt(string, key):
    encrypted = []
    encrypted.append(code_block(string, key))
    return " ".join(encrypted)

print(encrypt("This is a secret message", "12345678"))
```

Comment: This gives an output! However, it is not what I was expecting... is there anyway I would be able to make the function not consider the exclamation point, and just leave them on the end of the encrypted message??

Comment: @SamKennethGordon Yes take a look into edited code. It almost matches with your output. I have left it for you to solve it so that when 8 is added with s it becomes a. I can do that but it will be better if you try that yourself.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, is there anyway the encrypt function can leave the spaces and exclamation point in?

Comment: @SamKennethGordon Yes I have edited the code. Please re run the edited code.It will leave the spaces and exclamation as it is. And will match more with your output.

Comment: Thanks so much! You are a godsend! I have no idea how to implement the ' s -> key of 8 -> a ' thing? Is it something to do with inequalities? I feel like theres a lot of math involved to achieve it...

Comment: Well, there are lots of ways you can do it. But I suggest you to explore them and only then you can learn it.

Comment: I think I am close

`def code_char(c, key):
    if 65 <= ord(c) and ord(c) <= 90:
        return chr((ord(c)+int(key)-65))
    else:
        return chr((ord(c)+int(key)-97))`

This gives me blank squares followed by the exclamation points as an output, do you know what is going on?

Comment: You don't need to do that much. Just check if they are not letters then don't call code_char function that will be better way to do it. Each time you call a function, it results into overhead.

Comment: So I don't need to edit the `code_char` function? Where should I do this checking? The `encrypt` function or the `code_block` ?

Comment: @SamKennethGordon did you check the above code. I am already doing that. This is the line ==> if isletter(letter):

Comment: @KaudhalKumarSingh Oh my goodness, my brain is being fried! This programming stuff is not easy! Would you be able to give me a prompt in the right direction? I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see.

In this function

```
def code_block(word,key):
    letters = list(word)
    keys = list(key)
    coded = []
    for letter, digit in zip(letters, keys):
        coded.append(code_char(letter, digit))
    return "".join(coded)
```

the for loop can only iterate through the number of times of the smaller list. Example if I had

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list_2 = [111, 222, 333]
for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2)
    print (i, j)
```

I'd get

```
>>> (1, 111)
>>> (2, 222)
>>> (3, 333)
```

so you'd have to be passing in a key that is the same length as your string.

I'm guessing that your key string is the same length as `Ujlw%oz(`

On another note it looks like you're only checking if the first character of string is a character. Rather then checking all the characters in a string are actually characters. so you end up converting the white space with your function `code_char` in your code block loop.

```
def encrypt(string, key):
    for character in string:
        if isletter(character):
            return code_block(string, key)
        else:
            print("Invalid Message or Key")
```

So, I would say rethink your code so that you're checking for every character in the string. Most of the functionality is there, things just need to be tweaked.

Other note, it would be helpful to see the input arguments along with the expected output and received output that you posted.